# How to add different link on each Post

Tags: themes

Hello Guys am creating a wordpress theme but how can i implement  a download link on each post that is different from each other.

Comment: In your current format, your question will likely not get the best answers. Please rework your question after reading [ask]. Here [are some additional hints](http://www.takipiblog.com/2014/02/03/the-anatomy-of-a-great-stack-overflow-question-after-analyzing-10000/?utm_content=buffer5a8b2&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) collected to provide a good question that will attract good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can . If you want to add one/many file in your post , then you have to create custom field . There is a plugin called ACF ,this will help you to do so very easily . Please have a look to the link below

[Advance custom field file upload](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom filed for Download that post type. You can check below link how to add custom meta fields in post http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: Your answer is also correct but I have to be sincerely, and I give the credit to the first post. Thank you very much, you saved me alot of job